# Wordpress Mobile Edition not working with WP v3.5

Tags: mobile

Since upgrading Wordpress from 3.4.2 to 3.5, Wordpress Mobile Edition has not worked.

I have left a support request on the plugin's support page, but have received no reply in 2 weeks.  I might have to conclude the plugin author is no longer supporting this plugin.

I know this question might breach guidelines, but is there a ready alternative to using Wordpress Mobile Edition?

Perhaps this doesn't have to be a plugin, but might be a Wordpress hack.

I have a customised version of Carrington Mobile I'd like to retain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you are using hasn't been updated in 2 years.

Check out the [Jetpack for WordPress plugin](http://jetpack.me/). It comes with MANY useful modules, one of which is the **Mobile Theme** module.

Another plugin that comes to mind is [WPtouch](http://www.bravenewcode.com/product/wptouch-pro/), which is available in basic and pro ($$) builds.

Comment: Thanks Mr Binary.  Can the Mobile Themes be edited in both instances?

Comment: @Steve Yes. If you know PHP and have some working knowledge with wordpress. Why not just try 'em? They're free.